# How to close ant design drawer after click in-side the drawer

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I have used ant design drawer to display menu items, now I want to close the drawer when someone clicks the menu item. Write now we can only close the drawer on click outside the drawer it means drawer masked area.

```
<Drawer
                className="draw-body"
                placement="right"
                closable={false}
                onClose={onClose}
                visible={visible}
            >
                
                
                
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Nav.Link  key="1" as={Link} to="/">
                        <DashboardOutlined style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: '#fff' }} /> Dashboard
                    </Nav.Link>
                    {menuList}
                </Nav>
                <Nav>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={12}>
                            {!sidebar?(
                                <Nav.Link>
                                    <a href="#" onClick={() => handleLogout()}><LogoutOutlined style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: '#fff' }}/> Logout</a>
                                </Nav.Link>
                                
                                ) : null }
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={12}>
                            <Nav.Link  key="1" as={Link} to={routePaths.RESET_PASSWORD} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                                <RollbackOutlined style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: '#fff' }} />
                                <span className="menu-size"> Change Password </span>
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={12}>
                            <Nav.Link  key="1" as={Link} to={props.personProfileMenu} style={{ color: '#fff' }}>
                                <Icon type="user" style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: '#fff' }}/>
                                <span className="menu-size"> My Profile </span>
                            </Nav.Link>
                        </Col>                                
                    </Row>
                </Nav>
            </Drawer>
```

Can anyone please suggest some method to close the drawer on click in-side drawer.
[image]

Comment: @bernatsampera can you please look into this

Answer (score 1):

You can close the drawer by controlling the value of the `visible` prop on your drawer.

So the menu item that you want to hide the drawer with could handle an `onClick` event using a handler function that sets the value of `visible` to `false`.

*I'm assuming you're using a functional component and you have a `visible` state and setter defined using `useState` like this:*

```
const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
```

You can go about it in multiple ways, but one is to use the `Button` component with type `text` as the close drawer menu item:

```
<Button
  onClick={() => setVisible(false)}
  icon={<CloseOutlined style={{ fontSize: '18px', color: 'black' }} />}
  type="text">
  <span className="menu-size">Close Drawer</span>
</Button>
```

You could also make an icon only button on the top right corner of the drawer by setting absolute position:

```
<Button
  icon={<CloseOutlined />}
  onClick={() => setVisible(false)}
  type="text"
  style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, right: 0 }}
/>
```

*I've used the `CloseOutlined` icon in this example, but replace this with whatever you want.*

Answer (score 0):

there is a good solution i came up with:

```
const location = useLocation();
  useEffect(() => {
    onClose(); // close your denter code hererawer when ever the url chanes
  }, [location]);
```